# JSF - Filter text box appearence in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following CSS

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.taskFilter {
    float: left;
    padding-left: -5px;
    border: 1px;
}
</style>
```

Usage of this CSS in JSF

```
<rich:column sortBy="#{report.taskName}"
id="taskName" filterMethod="#{myBean.filterTaskName}" />
<f:facet name="header">
<h:panelGroup>
<h:outputText value="Task Name" />
<h:inputText class="taskFilter" value="#{myBean.filterValue}" id="filterInput"
onclick="Event.stop(event)">
<a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="dataTable, ds" ... />
...
</rich:column>
```

Works fine in Firefox and Chrome, here's how it looks:
[image]

However IE renders it weirdly:

[image]

Is there any workaround for this?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `input` is in its own row clear the `float` so you have:

```
.taskFilter {
    float: left;
    clear:both;
    padding-left: -5px;
    border: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I have tested you code in jsfiddle and it works fine. What's not working for you?